# How to understand the solution?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Two days ago,I have a problem about $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n \log (n)}$,and the @Julien Clancy give me a solution:

To see whether $\sum_2^\infty 1/(n \log n)$ converges, we can use the integral test. This series converges if and only if this integral does:
$$
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x \log x} dx = \left[\log(\log x)\right]_2^\infty
$$
and in fact the integral diverges.

I know the Infinite series $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n \log (n)}$ can be see as a area of trapezoid with curved edge that the $Delta x$=1,so the $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n \log (n)}$ is less than the `Integrate[1/(x*Ln(x),{x,2,Infinity}]`.

However,I cannot understand why the latter integral converge can reduct the former series converge?Can someone tell me why?Thanks sincerely!

Comment: Are you asking why the integral diverges? Or are you asking why the divergence of the integral implies the divergence of the series? For the latter, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summation would converge if the integral converges. This is the integral test. If the integral does not converge, then the infinite series does not converge.
I suggest you have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ satisfies
$f(x) > 0$
and
$f'(x) < 0$,
then
$f(n) 
> \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\, dx
> f(n+1)
$.

Summing,
$\sum_{n=a}^b f(n) 
> \int_a^{b+1} f(x)\, dx
> \sum_{n=a+1}^{b+1} f(n)
$.

Letting $b \to \infty$ shows why
convergence of the sum and the integral
are equivalent
for such functions.

This is, of course,
absolutely not original.

If you use better approximations
for the integral,
you are on the way to
the Euler-Maclaurin 
formula.